# How to use modular js files (with 'export') in a regular html file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Recently I've built some useful .js functions working in React environments where I've enjoyed the benefits and ergonomics of an overall more modular js workflow, but I was exploring the possibility of using them seamlessly in a 'stackless', vanilla environment.  Ie, just a regular `.html` file.

**So let's say I have this nifty function inside `module.js`:**

```
const myFunction = () => {
    console.log("success")
}

export default myFunction
```

...which works fine in setups like create-react-app, **but I just want to use my nifty function in boring old `index.html`**:

```
<script src="./module.js"></script>
```

... won't work, we can check the console and see the following:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`

so apparently we need to add `type="module"` to our `<script>` tags like so:

```
<script src="./module.js" type="module"></script>
```

No more error! **But we still can't use `myFunction()`** - We can try calling it in the console or adding it straight into our `index.html`, but no matter what we can't access `myFunction()`.

Furthermore, if I do the following:

```
<script type="module">
        import myFunction from "./module.js";
        myFunction();
</script>
```

...and actually import myFunction as I normally would and then immediately run it, we will in fact get our 'success' log in the console.

...however, if I try to use myFunction() elsewhere in other script tags, we will not have access:

```
<script type="module">
    import myFunction from "./module.js"; myFunction();
</script>

<script>
    myFunction();
</script>
```

...we will receive `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`

---

**Objective:**
If I have a number of useful modules I've built in react environments, **how can I *seamlessly* repurpose them for 'vanilla' projects in plain old html?**

I have explored a number of workarounds and changes we can make to the files to make them compatible (simply removing the `export` keywords altogether and dropping the modularity for example), but none of them convince me I actually know what the real problem is here, and none of them **suit the objective of not having to rewrite all my modules in some way.**

Imagine I have a number of npm packages that I don't want to have to mess around with just to use in a vanilla environment. I would lose all the convenience of being able to just `npm i my-package`.

Is there truly no way to use modular js like this without having to make modified 'vanilla' versions of all my code?